# Use Async in Lambda

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, lambda

I'm trying to setup up sequential asynchronous calls in my lambda function. I'm using the standard async library for this and haven't had a successful run of all the console prints.

```
// async import
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    async.waterfall([
        function func1(){
            console.log('1');
        },
        function func2(){
            console.log('2');
        },
        function func3(){
            console.log('3');
        },
    ], function (error, success) {
        if (error) { console.log('Something is wrong!'); }
        callback(null, 'success');
    });
};
```

All I see is :

```
START RequestId: b9dc249e-53ce-11e7-923a-95d7e896a384 Version: $LATEST
2017-06-18T02:35:00.915Z    b9dc249e-53ce-11e7-923a-95d7e896a384    1
END RequestId: b9dc249e-53ce-11e7-923a-95d7e896a384
REPORT RequestId: b9dc249e-53ce-11e7-923a-95d7e896a384  Duration: 2.
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a callback to each of the functions, to tell async when the next function should run.

This is much more complicated than just using promises, but we'll go with it.

```
async.waterfall([
  (next) => {
    console.log(1);
    next(2);
  },
  (valueIs2, next) => {
    console.log(valueIs2);
    next(valueIs2 + 1, valueIs2 - 1);
  },
  (valueIs3, valueIs1, next) => {
    next(valueIs3 - valueIs1);
  },
], (error, result) =>
  console.log(error ? `Error: ${error}` : `Result: ${result}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the internal callback of waterfall tasks, which tells the program to go to next task.

So, you just have to add a callback in your code and it will work:

```
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

async.waterfall([
    function func1(done){
        console.log('1');
        done(); // now this will go to next task
    },
    function func2(done){
        console.log('2');
        done(); // now this will go to next task
    },
    function func3(done){
        console.log('3');
        done(null); // => err = null
    },
], function (error, success) {
    if (error) { console.log('Something is wrong!'); }
    callback(null, 'success');
});
};
```

Check this documentation: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

Comment: You're not wrong, but the guy above here first with the same kind of logic. +1